# Database in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I cannot find where the database in my Rails application is located. I looked in folders like `/db`, `/db/migrate`, and `/app/models`, but cannot find the actual database that I can open to examine the data. Where is it located?

Comment: What do you have defined as your database in `config/database.yml`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try running `rails dbconsole` from the command line while you're inside your project directory.

Comment: And before THAT, if you haven't already, fill in `config/database.yml` with the appropriate stuff.

Comment: Looks like it's already been configured by my host... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

If you're running a SQLite Db (which rails runs by default), you can download SQLite DB Browser (http://sqlitebrowser.sourceforge.net/), and open your db/sqlite3 file to view the actual data, or if you're using mysql, check out: http://www.sequelpro.com/